# Gradient boosting on Vowpal Wabbit

Tags: machine-learning, vowpalwabbit

Is there a way to use gradient boosting on regression using Vowpal Wabbit? I use various techniques that come with Vowpal Wabbit that are helpful. I want to try gradient boosting along with that, but I can't find a way to implement gradient boosting on VW.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The idea of [gradient boosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting) is that an ensemble model is built from black-box weak models. You can surely use VW as the black box, but note that VW does not offer decision trees, which are the most popular choice for the black-box weak models in boosting. Boosting in general decreases bias (and increases variance), so you should make sure that the VW models have low variance (no overfitting). See [bias-variance tradeoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff).

There are some reductions related to boosting and bagging in VW:

- `--autolink N` adds a link function with polynomial N, which can be considered a simple way of boosting.
- `--log_multi K` is an online boosting algorithm for K-class classification. See [the paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.1822). You can use it even for binary classification (K=2), but not for regression.
- `--bootstrap M` M-way bootstrap by online importance resampling. Use `--bs_type=vote` for classification and `--bs_type=mean` for regression. Note that this is [bagging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating), not boosting.
- `--boosting N` (added on 2015-06-17) online boosting with N weak learners, see [a theoretic paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.02651)

Comment: Thanks for the help, appreciate it!

Comment: A very relevant paper on "Online Gradient Boosting" http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04820 was published yesterday. VW is mentioned there.